# Ansible - check if service exists, then execute tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have an Ansible playbook which allows listing services (`Postgres`, `ElasticSearch`, `MongoDB`, `MySQL`) and their versions installed on the machines.

I would like to add a condition which skips the task if the service does not exist.

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```yaml
when: "'postgresql.service' in services"
```

I configured this is task to scan for services:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Gather services
    service_facts:
    become: true
  - name: Filter services
    set_fact:
      services_app: "{{ services | dict2items
        | selectattr('value.state', 'match', 'running')
        | selectattr('value.source', 'match', service_mgr | string)
        | selectattr('value.name', 'search', (services_to_scan | join('|')))
        | map(attribute='key') | list | default([]) }}"
```

And this is the task to scan for `postgresql.service`:

```yaml
- name: Check Postgresql
  shell: psql --version
  register: psql

- name: debbuger la version Postgres
  debug: var=psql.stdout_lines
  when: "'postgresql.service' in services"
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it, first you need to [populate the services list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html).

```yaml
- name: Populate service facts
  ansible.builtin.service_facts:

- name: retrieve postgresql version when service is available
  shell: psql --version
  when: "'postgresql.service' in services"
```